# High CPU usage with css

Tags: html, css

I have an issue with my CSS solution that I had came up with. I have a list with 3000 rows or so and they each have the following css applied to each row:

```
.row .title,
.row .description {
    position: relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background-color: inherit;
}

.row .title:after,
.row .description:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 10%;
    height: 100%;
    background:linear-gradient(to right,rgba(255,255,255,0),rgba(255,255,255,1));           
}
```

Here is a sample row:

```
<tr class="row"><td class="title">really long test data string</td><td class="description">Test description</td></tr>
```

Basically what I am trying to do is fade out the text when the window is smaller than the table width. The problem is that I am always having high CPU usage when scrolling through the table, so it's non-responsive almost all the time. I realized it was this snippet of CSS that was causing this, but does anyone know of a way to make this work without causing high CPU usage. Maybe I am approaching this situation wrong? Anyone have any thoughts?

thanks!

Comment: _"I have a list with 3000 rows"_. Pagination perhaps?

Comment: it starts out with 100, and then as the user scrolls to the bottom it keeps grabbing rows, but overall when there is more than 1000 rows or so it starts the performance issues

Comment: what about setting the gradient once in table tag, or even from the <col> tag , so it is once drawn

Comment: Is removing the gradient helping? Maybe add `overflow:hidden` on the second rule to help a little (if it doesn't ruin the design)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `.row>.title` and `.row>.description` - the `>` combinator is more efficient than the `[space]` combinator, because it only has to travel one level of the hierarchy instead of all of them.

Normally this won't make much difference, but with 3,000 rows it could.

Also, consider adding `table-layout: fixed` to your table. You may need to add some HTML:

```
<table style="table-layout:fixed">
    <colgroup>
        <col style="width: 50px" />
        <col style="width: 250px" />
    </colgroup>
    <tbody>
        <tr>...</tr>
        ...
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This will allow the browser rendering engine to fix the table layout rather than making it dynamic based on the content - this will add up to a *massive* improvement for your huge table.

Comment: gradient can be applied from col tags too a very flasy test : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/ybDhH

Comment: @GCyrillus Possibly, but OP has a "foreground" gradient here with the `:after` psuedoelement.

Comment: here is the idea about the <col> : col {
  background:linear-gradient(to left,rgba(255,255,255,1)  , rgba(255,255,255,0.5), rgba(255,255,255,0) ) right no-repeat;          
  background-size:10% 100%;
}

Comment: That's still background, though. The idea is to give the text the appearance of fading out.

Comment: oki, what are the background color and text-color, i guess it is not white text over balck screen then , arf !

Answer (score 0):

change your selectors to something more specific, e.g.:

```
.rowtitle,
.rowdescription {
    position: relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background-color: inherit;
}
```

or direct descendant if it suits your markup:

```
.row > .title,
.row > .description { 
    position: relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background-color: inherit;
}
```

cascading selectors are more expensive because the browser traverses the DOM right to left when interpreting a css selector.

you can measure your css selectors performance with Chrome dev tools, "Profiles" and use the "Collect CSS Selector Profile".